# How to handle a situation when I have references to an object that should be removed

Tags: c#, design

I have a situation like this: in my online game, players are represented by class Player, which is instantiated and assigned their socket upon their connection to the server.
When simplified, some of my code looks like this:

```
class Monster
{
  Player targetedPlayer;

   void FollowPlayer(Player p)
   {
      targetedPlayer=p;
   }
}
```

But I realized that I guess I should not work with references to players because when the player disconnects (I did implement IDispose), the reference in the targetPlayer will still point to an object that is not released because of that. 
Obivously I would need that when a player disconnects, all references to his Player instance become null because he is no longer in the game. What would be the best solution?

Comment: What should a Monster do when the Player he is following suddenly disappears (disconnects)? How would the Monster class know that the person behind the Player class is no longer there? (Hint: Player class knows about the Monster and informs him, or Player class has a method that the Monster class can periodically call).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau In my design, when the reference to the player is null, monster randomly roams around. I somehow forgot that just disconnecting the player does not automatically make the reference invalid. Player does not necessarily knows about monsters as they can target him silently jsut because he gets too close to them. One possible way would be for monsters to look into the player's file to see if he is still logged in the game (I use files for players' data, and a flag is set to OFFLINE when server detects disconnection)

Comment: There might be a difference between the information that the Player object in the game engine knows and the information that gets presented to the human player. It is entirely possible that the Player object has a list of all Monsters following him, but presents only a subset of that list to the human player.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Currently I do not have it like that, the player only holds a reference to the last interacted NPC, be it a monster or a merchant. Just thinking about a 
 Disconnect event that the Monster would subscribe to, but not sure if that is not overkill

Comment: Such an event would *not* be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you are dealing with different threads.

Implement an event Disposed on Player and have Monster subscribe to it.
Add a private lock object to Monster (any instance of object will do).

In whatever Monster method you deal with player, lock on this object. Within the lock, check for your player reference being null and work on it only if it is not null.

In your monster's Player_Disposed handler, apply the same lock and null your player reference.

This will do it for Monster as long as you do not invoke threads from within the lock that may call code using that same lock. This would deadlock your application.

Now Player will have to safeguard itself against being called upon after it has been disposed, or while it is being disposed. You can use a similar method to do this. If Player is disposed and receives a call you probably want to ignore it.